# Exact sampling distribution of Kendall's tau under independence (no ties case)

Tags: r, kendall-tau, concordance, sampling-distribution

I am looking for an R package for calculating **the CDF and the inverse-CDF** of the **sample Kendall's tau (*)** under the null assumption of independence, in the case of no ties.

(*) Just to be clear, I am referring to the statistic $\hat{\tau}$ that measures concordance or monotonic correlation for a random sample $\{(X_1, Y_1), \dots, (X_n,Y_n)\}$ of a bivariate continuous random variable $(X,Y)$, assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

The only package I found so far is `SuppDists`. It provides the functions `dKendall`, `pKendall`, `qKendall` and `rKendall`. In the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SuppDists/SuppDists.pdf), it says:

> The calculated values are exact for $n < 13$, thereafter an Edgeworth expansion is used.

More precisely, for small values of $n$, it seems that exact calculations are done following Hajek & Sidak (1967, p. 140). I found this out by reading the underlying C code. If I am not wrong, it makes reference to a recursive formula (I don't have the edition of 1967, but a more recent one).

Anyway, **does anyone know about a package implementing an exact calculation of the CDF and the inverse-CDF of the sample Kendall's tau for larger values of $n$?**

---

REFERENCES

Hajek J, Sidak Z (1967). Theory of rank tests. Academic Press, New York.

Comment: I am not completely familiar with the exact CDF, but doesn't it involve some combinatorics that can get very large very quickly? In that case, calculating the exact CDF may simply be computationally infeasible for larger $n$, and you simply won't find what you are looking for. Then again, depending on when the original code was written, computers may be faster nowadays such that one could perhaps reasonably extend the exact calculation to a larger value than $n=12$.

Comment: The `Kendall` function of the [Kendall package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Kendall/Kendall.pdf) computes the exact p-value when there are no ties, according to the documentation. Maybe you could find an answer by looking at the code.